# Why is this coming back undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
<span class="randomClassName">words</span>


function GetCartAmount(){
    var x = document.getElementByClassName("randomClassName")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
}
```

I am trying to get the text inside the class above to be logged in the console, but no matter what it says undefined.

I have tried to get other classes with text and each one is undefined.

Is there something wrong with my javascript?

Comment: Just in case you've missed the obvious it is getElementsByClassName your example doesn't have the s.

Comment: Something i hadn't notice, but it still says undefined when fixed

Comment: Actually that does seem to be the problem, when i fixed it i added an extra s by accident.

Comment: So.. do you still have a problem or not?

Comment: No just waiting on the 7minutes to be up so i can select my answer

Comment: That essentially is the real code all changed was my class names sense the real class name was a long mess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're trying to use `getElementByClassName()` and not `getElement*s*ByClassName()`.

Your code is throwing a `TypeError` as it is now.

Working example (in Chrome, FF and Safari)

http://jsbin.com/EgEBUCi/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using `getElementByClassName`, not `getElementsByClassName`.
Try:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("randomClassName")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I actually had it like that, my mistake for not including that in the question, i will edit it now.

Comment: Edited with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should try (you are missing `s` in `getElementByClassName`):

```
function GetCartAmount(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("randomClassName")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getElementsByClassName('randomClassName')[0].innerHTML
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("randomClassName")[0].innerHTML;
```